# User locker Oracle 11g

Tags: database, oracle11g

I have a user who, if I consult the tables of his scheme, if I try to compile a package or if I try to log in with the user, the base is blocked. The problem is that it is the user in which I have most of my things. Does anyone know why this problem is due and / or its solution?

Comment: What does "base is blocked" mean?

Comment: I can not enter the base with the user, I could do it, but it works slow and the connection cuts off after a few minutes

Comment: I'm not very good at English and I'm using a translator, maybe that confuses, sorry

Comment: So, you have difficulties in establishing connection? Is that your local database (installed on your computer), or do you access it over the network? Is there any sysadmin or DBA you can talk to?

Comment: The administrator is me. The issue is that I connect locally, but the user works slowly, when I connect with another user and try to compile for example a package of the metered user, everything is locked, it is like the scheme of the user is corrupted. I don't know what problem I have

Comment: Is there enough memory on the database server? CPU?

Comment: Yes, do not control the tableaspace, now I notice

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: Tablespace have space, except temp.